Viscous stress, and closed dynamic equations for density and velocity fields of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?
Context
I am trying to write simple derivation of hydrodynamic definition of viscous stress $\partial^{2}_{x}v$ based on OU-process which is
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= v \\
\dot{v} &= -\gamma v + \xi
\end{align}
Question
Does this process have $\partial^{2}_{x}v$ in the momentum equation? i.e does $\partial_{t}v$ have a term $\partial^{2}_{x}v$ in it?
What is the simplest way to generalize OU to derive viscous stress ? i.e what is most simple stochastic equation giving rise to viscous stress ?
How to derive Newton's law of viscous stress ?

Do you mean the Dean Kawasaki equation? or perhaps the Fockker-Planck equation of the OU? In the OU, $x,v$ only have time dependence, your spatial partial derivatives have no meaning

Consider $v(x, t) = \int dv v P(x, v, t) / P(x, t)$ and $\rho (x, t) = \int dv P(x, v, t) $ so spatial derivatives have a lot of meaning. Fokker-Planck equation of OU describes dynamics of $P(x, v, t)$ but for dynamics of density and velocity fields the zeroth and first velocity moments must calculated.

I was just pointing out that there is a conflict of notation. On the one hand you have the stochastic variable $v$ which depends on time which defines OU and your quantity $u:=\mathbb E(v|x)$. You should define it and name it clearly in your question to avoid confusion.

No such terms arise from many body interactions and would not appear for a free particle. For a free particle, the stress would simply be the ideal gas pressure. See for example the SI of https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/158/7/074904/2877192/Tuning-nonequilibrium-phase-transitions-with (don't bother about thz magnetization field, it would be 0 at equilibrium, here they consider a non equilibrium system)

To partially answer your question, yes for a free particle you can easily obtain closed equation for the hydrodynamics field (which also include the temperature  or the stress... as you wish). These are simply the moments in velocity of the Fokker plank equation and this is what is done in the SI of the article I linked. For interacting particles (where interactions give the viscous stress you wqnt to see), you have to use some closure to obtaine closed hydrodynamical equations

@Syrocco Thanks for the reference. The appendix indeed contain helpful discussion but I am still confused, let me summarize why. Writing closed equations boils down to approximating $<v^{2}>$ in terms of $v$ and $\rho$. Although is here appearing in stochastic dynamics, this $<v^{2}>$ term also appears when deriving density and velocity fields from the Boltzmann equation, but it that case many authors argue that $<v^{2}>$ gives rise to deviatoric and volumetric stress so I would have expected the same here.

@Syrocco Another rough argument why I expected to see viscous stress from OU process is simply because viscous stress effectively acts as a diffusive term of the velocity distribution. As an analogy if we take Wiener process we see that random velocity implies diffusive term for the density, so I expected that random force implies diffusive term for the velocity.

So now my question is : What is the simplest way to generalize OU to derive viscous stress ? i.e what is most simple stochastic equation giving rise to viscous stress ?


yes , more correctly $\langle (v - \langle v\rangle)(v-\langle v\rangle)\rangle$ is the stress. Which again, has the non trivial contribution of viscosity coming from particles interactions (with the boltzmann equation, it will involve the collision operator. For a N langevin particle, it will involve the potential as a Irvin-Kirkwood stress). The trivial one which is simply the ideal gas pressure ($k_bT$) arises due to the noise.



indeed, there will be a "diffusive term" in the fokker plank equation for the velocity (see the Kleins Kramer equation) with a form of second derivative of probability with respect to the velocity. But this is not the sale as viscosity which effectively accounts for the microscopic interaction on the macroscopic scale and tries to make the average velocity of the fluid come to 0.



any stochastic processes with particle interaction will give rise to viscuous like stress. So you would have to add multiple particles. But the stress will be complicated to compute. Here is a very pedagogical article where the hydrodynamics equation of interacting active particles ( you can forget the magnetization field). https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/ac2b54 . However in the end, the form of the stress is most of the time assumed. You can derive it with the chapman enksog theory at close to equilibrium but it is hard.


Ah, maybe a more convincing argument as to why "diffusion" of velocity cannot be interpreted as viscosity. Viscosity will always conserve the momentum, random noise does not.

By the way the noise term will only affect the hydrodynamical temperature field but it will not affect the average velocity field.

Yes thanks for all comments, this gets close to good answer but it is still not clear. I find it remarkable that hydrodynamic form of viscous stress can not be derived from stochastic dynamics. Chapman-Enskog method approximates collison integral in Boltzmann equation, but here I look at stochastic dynamics.

I will have a look on stochastic dynamics of interacting particles, if you can write the simplest form of such system as I wrote in the question feel free to do so.

Hum, by chapman enskog I meant an expansion in termm of gradients of the fokker plank or any kinetic equation. Which would also works for stochastic dynamics. But yes yes, you are right, it might not be the right terminology.. I might write an answer if I find time! Sorry if my comments/arguments are a bit scattered and not clear.

As said in the comment, viscous stress comes from the interparticle interactions. Basically, it is what allows you to reach a thermal equilibrium for molecular fluid (without noise). Physically, it takes the form:
$$\nu\Delta \boldsymbol  u(x, t)$$
with $\boldsymbol  u(x, t)$ the macroscopic velocity field and can be interpreted as the collisions between the particles of the fluid trying to average the global macroscopic velocity. Note that, if all particles move in the same direction with a finite velocity, you do not have any viscous stress (because you do not have any collision). Note also that it conserves the momentum since $\partial_t\boldsymbol  u=\dots - \nu \nabla\cdot \nabla \boldsymbol  u$ has the form of the derivative of a current.

Now that it is settled, we can start to look at your equation:
\begin{align}
\dot{\boldsymbol x}_i &= \boldsymbol v_i \\
\dot{\boldsymbol v}_i &= -\gamma \boldsymbol v_i + \sqrt{2\gamma T}\boldsymbol \xi_i
\end{align}
with $v_i$ the microscopic velocity of particle $i$ that should not be conflated with $\boldsymbol u(x, t) = \sum_{i=1}^N\langle\boldsymbol v_i(t) \delta(\boldsymbol x- \boldsymbol x_i(t)) \rangle$ the macroscopic velocity.
From this we can derive a Fokker Plank equation. To do so, we can write it under the stupid form:
\begin{align}
\dot{\boldsymbol x}_i &= \boldsymbol v_i +  0\boldsymbol\eta_i\\
\dot{\boldsymbol v}_i &= -\gamma\boldsymbol v_i + \sqrt{2\gamma T}\boldsymbol\xi_i
\end{align}
where $\eta_i$ is a random noise, but that does not have any effect since it has 0 amplitude. Nonetheless, it allows you to see that a single underdamped particle can be seen as a system with two independent variables $x$ and $v$. In any case, you derive the Fokker-Plank as you would for a multivariate process:
$$\partial_t f(\boldsymbol x_1,\boldsymbol x_2, ..., \boldsymbol v_1, \boldsymbol v_2, t)= \sum_{i=1}^N- \partial_{\boldsymbol x_i} \cdot \boldsymbol j^{\boldsymbol x_i} - \partial_{\boldsymbol v_i} \cdot \boldsymbol j^{\boldsymbol v_i}$$
where $j^x$ and $j^v$ are respectively the probability current of position and velocity. These current, as usual include the drift term and the diffusion term linked to the amplitude of the noise:
$$\partial_t f(\boldsymbol x_1,\boldsymbol x_2, ..., \boldsymbol v_1, \boldsymbol v_2, t)= \sum_{i=1}^N- \partial_{\boldsymbol x_i}\cdot (\boldsymbol v_i f)  - \partial_{\boldsymbol v_i} \cdot (-\gamma \boldsymbol v_i f-\gamma T \partial_{\boldsymbol v_i} f)$$
In this case, the system is non interacting, thus:
$$\partial_t f(\boldsymbol x, \boldsymbol v, t)= - \partial_{\boldsymbol x}\cdot (\boldsymbol vf)  + \gamma\partial_{\boldsymbol v}\cdot(\boldsymbol vf)+\gamma T \partial_{\boldsymbol v}^2 f \tag 1$$
Which is called the Klein-Kramers equation.

Now to derive the hydrodynamics equations from this, we simply have to take the moment of the equation:
$$\rho(\boldsymbol x, t) = \int f(\boldsymbol x, \boldsymbol v, t) d\boldsymbol v$$
$$ \rho\boldsymbol u(x, t) = \int vf(\boldsymbol x, \boldsymbol v, t) d\boldsymbol v$$
$$-\boldsymbol\sigma(x, t) = \int f(x, v, t)\boldsymbol v\otimes\boldsymbol v d\boldsymbol v$$
I let you convince yourself that this definition for the macroscopic velocity is the same as the one I gave above. $\boldsymbol \sigma$ is the kinetic stress tensor, in an interacting system, you would also have an interacting contribution. And you would most likely consider the temperature field $\langle (v-u)^2\rangle$ instead of the kinetic stress tensor as an hydrodynamic field... But in any case, let's move on.
Density equation:
We integrate (1) with respect to $v$:
$$\partial_t \rho(\boldsymbol x, \boldsymbol v, t)= - \int\partial_{\boldsymbol x}\cdot (\boldsymbol vf) d\boldsymbol v  + \int \gamma\partial_{\boldsymbol v}\cdot(\boldsymbol vf)+\gamma T \partial_{\boldsymbol v}^2 fd\boldsymbol v=-\partial_{\boldsymbol x} \cdot (\rho u)$$
The second term can be integrated immediately and vanishes due to the vanishing of the probability at the boundaries. This is a continuity equation
Momentum equation:
$$\partial_t (\rho u)= - \int\partial_{\boldsymbol x}\cdot(\boldsymbol v\otimes \boldsymbol v f) d\boldsymbol v  +\int \gamma\boldsymbol v\partial_{\boldsymbol v}\cdot(\boldsymbol vf)d\boldsymbol v+ \int\gamma T \boldsymbol v\partial_{\boldsymbol v}^2 fd\boldsymbol v=\partial_{\boldsymbol x}\cdot \boldsymbol\sigma-\gamma\rho u$$
The last term vanishes because $v\partial_v^2f=\partial_v (v\partial_v f) - \partial_vf$ and hence is pure boundary. And the second term comes from the integration by part: $\partial_v(v^2f)=vf+v\partial_v(vf)$. Note the absence of the noise term in the momentum field.
Kinetic stress tensor
$$\partial_t \sigma= \int (\boldsymbol v\otimes \boldsymbol v)\partial_{\boldsymbol x}\cdot (\boldsymbol vf) d\boldsymbol v  - \int \gamma(\boldsymbol v\otimes \boldsymbol v)\partial_{\boldsymbol v}\cdot(\boldsymbol vf)d\boldsymbol v-\int\gamma T (\boldsymbol v\otimes \boldsymbol v)\partial_{\boldsymbol v}^2 fd\boldsymbol v=-\partial_{\boldsymbol x} \cdot \tilde{\boldsymbol  {J}}-2\gamma \boldsymbol \sigma - 2 \gamma T\rho \boldsymbol{1}$$
$\tilde{\boldsymbol J}$ is related to the heat flux and is proportional to $\langle \boldsymbol u\otimes \boldsymbol u\otimes \boldsymbol u\rangle$. The other terms are found by integration by part. But I'm tired to type them out! We could derive a fourth equation for the time evolution of $J$ but it would involve a quantity proportional to a power 4 of $u$ and so on... This is never ending and we have to assume a closing equation. Here we simply assume it to be non contributing.

We finally have all the equations we wanted. A first thing we can do is look at the steady state of the stress equation. It gives $\boldsymbol \sigma = -\rho T \boldsymbol 1$ which is simply the hydrostatic pressure of an ideal gas. Putting it into the momentum equation you see that there is no viscosity involved. And basically, we derived Euler's equation, but for a colloidal system (the arrival to equilibrium is done by the bath and not by the hydrodynamic modes/collisions/interactions in the fluid.).

What's missing is of course interactions. Viscosity allows the system to reach thermal equilibrium and without interaction between the particles, you are sure that you could not reach it (without an external bath as postulated here at least!). Adding an interaction term would have added a non trivial contribution to the momentum equation under the form of a interacting stress tensor. But this would also have modified the equation for the kinetic stress tensor. For example, this is what happens with the Boltzmann equation where your contribution for the stress tensor is purely kinetic but the collision term allows you to have non hydrostatic contribution to the stress tensor (see Kardar book for example, but you seem familiar with the Enskog method).

To go further here are some references:
Derivation of underdamped hydrodynamics with solvent 1, 2
The canonical reference for the derivation of stress tensor in many body systems (without using Boltzmann equations, and with real potential) 3
An alternative approach by Dean to derive (fluctuating) hydrodynamic equation from a langevin equation 4 and the underdamped case 5 (be carefull the hydrostatic contribution in this thing is not clear until you go to the overdamped regime)

Here I approached the question from a different angle
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/816889/microscopic-derivation-of-newtons-law-of-viscosity
