Microscopic derivation of Newtons law of viscosity?
Newtons viscosity law says that viscous stress is proportional to spatial velocity gradient. When used in hydrodynamic problems it results in the Laplacian of the velocity field appearing in the momentum equation. It effectively acts to smooth out velocity gradients and it is motivated by thermal fluctuations that tend to smooth out velocity gradients.
I try to derive Newtons viscosity law by deriving hydrodynamic equations of velocity field $ v(x, t) $ in terms of a density gradient term and velocity gradient term starting from discrete particle coordinates. I try changing from a discrete sum over particle indices $ i $ to a continuous sum over particle coordinates at time $ t $, denoted $ x'$.
For a set of $ N $ particles with positions $ x_i^t $ and velocities $v_i^t$ we define the velocity field as $ v(x, t) = \sum_{i=1}^N v_i^t \delta(x - x_i^t) $

Time Derivative of the Velocity Field:

$ \partial_t v(x, t) = \sum_i \partial_t (v_i^t \delta(x - x_i^t)) $

Expanding the Time Derivative:

Using the product rule and assuming $\dot v_i^t = 0$
$ \partial_t v(x, t) = \sum_i \left( \partial_t v_i^t \delta(x - x_i^t) + v_i^t \partial_t \delta(x - x_i^t) \right) = \sum_i  v_i^{t2} \partial_x \delta(x - x_i^t) $

Converting to Continuous Variables:

Denoting the set of positions $ x_i^t $ at time $ t $ as $x'$:
$ \partial_t v(x, t) = \partial_x \sum_{x'} v^2(x') \delta(x - x')  $
Assuming $x'$ can be represented as continuous variable, replacing the discrete sum with an integral over continuous coordinates $ x' $, applying the change of variables, and assuming velocities slightly scattered around mean $ v(x') = v + \delta v(x') $:
$ \partial_x \int dx' \left( \frac{v^2}{\delta x'} + v \frac{\delta v(x')}{\delta x'} + \frac{\delta v(x')^2}{\delta x'} \right) \delta(x - x') $
Velocity from first term factors out as it is constant and first term gives density after integration, fluctuation from third term neglected as it is small and third term is neglected

Density Gradient and Viscous Stress:

Forgetting about proportionality constants and recognizing the density gradient and viscous stress contributions:
$ \partial_t v(x, t) = \partial_x \rho(x, t) + \partial^2_x v(x, t) $

Final Dynamic Equation:

Combining these terms gives the dynamic equation for the velocity field:
$ \partial_t v = \partial_x \rho + \partial_x^2 v $
So I think small assuming small fluctuations in velocities around mean implies Newtons viscosity law. But I could not find such derivations in literature. Could you point references that try to do the procedure presented here with more details ? Or what am I doing wrong here ?

It seems to me that you are writing down an effective field theory in term of gradients where you include all possible terms that respect some constraints, symetries,.. (which is the modern wat of viewing hydrodynamics). This is of course correct and will give you the most general field theory you could obtain (albeit, without the transport coefficient that can depends on the field themselves..). So you should not be surprise to see a viscuous term appears since it is present in most field theories.

But again, if you try to derive this equation by, instead of including every terms, really derive them by a coarse graining, in a non interacting theory, you miss the viscosity. This is exactly what is done here https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4768, they start from your initial equation and derive the final hydrodynamic equation which is exact and contains viscosity under the form of an integrated potential (an effective free energy)

If you really, want a viscuous like term in a free theory, you must go see what we call "model B" type equations or in molecular dynamics Dissipative Particle Dynamics, the noise and the damping are basically constructed to conserve the momentum (as the viscosity does) instead of having non conserving noise and damping, as is usually done in classical langzvin equation (if you coarse grained such langevin equation, you do not obtain a nice hydrodynamic theory with everliving hydrodynamic modes because they are damped by the non momentum conserving damping)

If you want sources for the kind of construction you are doing, you should look at papers with keyword "effective field theory in hydroydamics". The high energy community likes this a lot so you will see probably a lot of relativity and/or quantum fluid but it also applies very well to classical field theory. I cannot give you a nice reference about this, I'm not very knowledgeable abt it. For dissipative particle dynamics here is a nice hydrodynamic derivation https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.52.1734 for an intro on the subject any well cite article or wikipedia will do

@Syrocco Thanks for reference arxiv.org/abs/0807.4768 they use same formalism indeed. But in going from equation 15 to 16 and when finally arriving to equation 28 they make remarkable mistakes. They replace the average of squared velocity with the squared average velocity, so they neglect fluctuations. However the second derivative term I derived comes precisely from those fluctuations. But I still agree with you that this "second derivative term" is different from viscosity arising from interactions.

I'm not too sure what's the average you are talking about. In their case, eq 16 I'd just a consequence of eq. 15 together with the properties of dirac eq. 14. But they do not average over any noise or anything. The equation is a (highly singular) stochastic differential equation. Then, I agree if you want the (smooth) velocity field, you must average somehow over the noise.

In eq 15 they have two sums over indices $i$ and $j$ with a product $p_{i}p_{j}$ but in equation 16 this product is written as $p_{i}p_{i}$

$\sum_i\sum_j p_ip_i\delta(x - x_i)\delta(x-x_j)=\sum_i\sum_j p_ip_i\delta(x - x_i)\delta(x_i-x_j)$ by the property $f(x)\delta(x - y) = f(y)\delta(x-y)$. They go on using Eq. 14 $\delta(x_i-x_j)=\delta(x_i-x_j)\delta_{ij}$ since no particles overlap. This gives: $\sum_i\sum_j p_ip_i\delta(x - x_i)\delta(x-x_j)=\sum_i\sum_j p_ip_i\delta(x - x_i)\delta(x_i-x_j)\delta_{ij}$. They use the same property but for the discrete $\delta$: $x_i\delta_{ij}=x_j\delta_{ij}$

Back at the equation: : $\sum_i\sum_j p_ip_i\delta(x - x_i)\delta(x_i-x_j)\delta_{ij}=\sum_i\sum_j p_ip_j\delta(x - x_i)\delta(x_i-x_j)\delta_{ij}$. They use again $\delta(x_i-x_j)=\delta(x_i-x_j)\delta_{ij}$ together with $f(x)\delta(x - y) = f(y)\delta(x-y)$ and finally find $\sum_i\sum_j p_ip_j\delta(x - x_i)\delta(x_i-x_j)\delta_{ij} =\sum_i\sum_j p_ip_j\delta(x - x_i)\delta(x-x_j)$. Everything is exact up to this point. This is just index trickery.
